# custom scrollview not appearing

Tags: android

I have a custom ScrollView that works fine if it is the only thing in the emulator.

For example, this works fine:

```
    public class Timeline2Activity extends Activity {
        private TimelineView tlv;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            tlv = new TimelineView(this);
            setContentView(tlv);
        }
    }
```

But if I first add widgets then it fails to appear.  I've searched and experimented for 2 days and nothing works.

Here is the class declaration of the custom ScrollView:

```
public class TimelineView extends ScrollView implements OnTouchListener {
```

And here are the constructors:

```
public TimelineView(Context context) {
    super(context);
this.setOnTouchListener(this);
setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}
//the following constructor is needed to inflate the view from XML
public TimelineView(Context context, AttributeSet ats) {
    super(context,ats);
this.setOnTouchListener(this);
setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}
```

Here is the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zoom All" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+" />
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/category_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/category_prompt"
    />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.projects.timeline2.TimelineView
        android:id="@+id/timeline_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the main program:

```
public class Timeline2Activity extends Activity {
    private TimelineView tlv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //tlv = new TimelineView(this);
        //setContentView(tlv);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Spinner spinnerCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCategory = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.categories, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterCategory.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerCategory.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
        spinnerCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
        //TimelineView tlv = (TimelineView) findViewById(R.id.timeline_view);
        //ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
        //container.addView(tlv);
    }
    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The selection is " +
              parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

The lines commented out are stuff I've tried but didn't work either.

This code correctly puts 3 buttons and a spinner in a horizontal row across the top.  But TimelineView fails to appear below them.  I know that TimelineView is running because I can see debugging output in the LogCat that I put in.

I'm at my wits end and hope someone can shed some light.  This seems like a common fundamental need and sure deserves a google tutorial.

Comment: Can you please give more information about what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You are using LinearLayout and you have used `android:layout_height="fill_parent`" to the first element so the first element will fill the whole screen height and there will be no space for the second element (com.projects.timeline2.TimelineView) thats why you are unable to see second element.

**Use Relative Layout instead**. and mention `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for second element so that it will always stay to the buttom of the screen and align the first element to the above of second by putting `android:layout_above` to first element

**Your XML will be**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



    <com.projects.timeline2.TimelineView

        android:id="@+id/timeline_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeline_view">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zoom All" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+" />
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/category_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="category_prompt"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I replaced my main.xml with yours but the same thing happened.  TimelineView fails to appear below the buttons.  Then I went back and changed the main program to include only the TimelineView, like before and it worked perfectly, so I know nothing in it is wrong.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change TimeLine's layout height to fill_parent in xml, or add some content to it.

Comment: I tried that and now TimeLineView does show up, but it fills the whole window, kicking out the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it.  Here is the main.xml that worked.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zoom All" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+" />
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/category_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.projects.timeline2.TimelineView
        android:id="@+id/timeline_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/buttons"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks everyone for getting me going in the right direction!